# How to change TextView Color Programmatically

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am stumped with this seemingly simple task.

I want to simply change the color of a `textview` and the background color of a `linearlayout` to colors set in my `colors.xml` resource file.

**I have tried:**

```
myTextView.SetTextColor(this.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.myColor));
```

But this is deprecated.

**I then tried:**

```
myTextView.SetTextColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.myColor));
```

But `ContextCompat.GetColor()` returns an `int` rather than an `Android.Graphics.Color` so won't compile.

**I then tried to instead set the color as part of a `style`:**

```
  <style name="myColorStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">
      @color/myColor
    </item>
...
  </style>
```

and set it  first using

```
myTextView.SetTextAppearance(this, Resource.Style.myColorStyle);
```

but this is also deprecated so

**I tried this:**

```
myTextView.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.myColorStyle);
```

but this throws an exception:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/widget/TextView;.setTextAppearance(I)V"

How is this simple task achieved?

I am coding in **C# using Xamarin** and Visual Studio.

Comment: it is necessary for you to get color from resources?

Comment: Did you try `myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000"));` OR `myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("red"));`

Comment: textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor));

Comment: I'm not sure how 1-1 Xamarin mirrors the Android APIs. But `resources.getColor(int)` was only deprecated on API23 to favour the version that a `Resource.Theme` can be used. That means two things: 1) you can ignore the deprecation; 2) you can use the other method with null: `resource.getColor(Resource.color.myColor, null);`

Comment: use new Android.Graphics.Color (ContextCompat.GetColor (this, Resource.Color.red)); don't forget about **constructor new Android.Graphics.Color ()**

Answer (score 17):

In 2017, this is somehow the correct way to get the color by resource id, even though it seems extremely convoluted:

```
new Android.Graphics.Color (ContextCompat.GetColor (this, Resource.Color.bb_orange));
```

per:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54193/res-getcolor-is-deprecated

Answer (score 7):

**not needed to be so complex, just use**

```
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000"));
```

**OR**

```
 myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
```

**OR**

```
myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the first of your suggestions at the moment, although it doesn't feel right to duplicate the XML resource in code! (Your 3rd suggestion is for Java but I am using Xamarin in C#, it is the equivalent method that is flagged for deprecation)

Comment: If it's deprecated then why not to use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.YOURCOLOR);`

Comment: Check my question at the top. `ContextCompat.getColor()` returns an int but `setTextColor()` expects a `Color` (which is what `Resources.GetColor()` returns)

Comment: `setTextColor()` accepts `int` too. See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int))]

Comment: myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000")); this will throw an error. It accept #rrggbb format only.

Answer (score 4):

Its quite simple, if you want to skip the xml.

```
  myTextView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
```

Also works for setting the background color of the text view.

```
myTextView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

I first do not noticed it, but I see that you've tried this solution. What version are you using? In my it is not deprecated.

```
 textView.SetTextColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.red));
```

In Resources/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
  <color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
</resources>
```

[Xamarin Resource.Color](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Resource+Color/)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015, with Xamarin 4.0.1.145 and Xamarin.Android 6.0.2.1

Comment: i cannot try it in this version, but you can try :
try use Get ColorStateList instead GetColor
What value returned ContextCompat.GetColor ()? It can be int id forTemp Id resources? Or maybe RGB color represented as int istead RGB?

Answer (score 0):

**myTextView.TextColor = Color.Parse("Red");**